# How do I build a defensively focused Battlemind at level 1?

Tags: dnd-4e, battlemind

Can someone give a good idea to get a defensive Battlemind build that will work well with the following party at level 1?

- Drow Warlock (dark pact),
- Longtooth shifter ranger,
- Dwarf Healing cleric (Hopefully),
- Goliath Barbarian
- and soon to be a Battlemind,

We need a good tank to take a lot of damage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: read the [handbook](http://web.archive.org/web/20150923002128/http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3013826). Battlemind is a delightful class, but complicated.

Step 2: Read the art of [defending](http://web.archive.org/web/20130909161029/http://community.wizards.com/wiki/Dnd:CharOp/Defenders). and MMO mentality. Defenders who try to get everyone in the battle to focus on them... die. The battlemind will be protecting the squishy warlock, and should aim to take 2-3 monsters on at a time.

Some notes:

A wis secondary will get you battle resilience and Iron Fist. Grab Vicious Cobra Strike as your second at-will, and make sure to have a heavy shield and scale armor. Living fortress does what it says on the tin, as cover makes you even *more* annoying to hit. Oaken Resilience at level 2 gives you another resist, and Shade Strike at 3 gives you concealment. Aim towards getting Radiant Recovery through Deva Heritage if you want more THP as well.

With THP from RR, and concealment from shade form, it's quite possible to go through a battle without taking damage. At level 1, you *will* take damage, but the leader should have you right as rain in no-time. Make sure you're getting the THP from the leader until you can generate your own.

Comment: having good defenses as a defender is essential to your job in the party. However, your defenses shouldn't be *too* high. Especially intelligent monsters will wander off to stab the squishies after a round or two if they realize they need a 16+ to hit the defender. Since most mark punishing mechanics are based on an immediate action the defender in that case can do little to prevent the wizard or warlock from getting ganged on. I have just that situation in my *Scales of War* party: swordmage AC 28 + shaman AC 17 + rest of party between AC 20 and 25.

Comment: It depends. With a battlemind, the whole "wander off and hit someone else" mechanic is quite difficult to achieve. It also means that you don't have a buddy that you're actively protecting. Furthermore, high defenses were the purpose of this question (and resist > AC from plate at level 1) The problem with the swordmage is that they have no way of saying *PAY ATTENTION* On the other hand, the swordmage also doesn't need to engage their marked target. What kind of swordmage? You may want to make that a question. (Also, that's an awfully low shaman AC, is he/she doing things correctly?